# Improvement of Game Tree in Forest with continuum of moves

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-trees, forest, game-tree

I need help with an application within the Forest environment. I would like to create a game tree in Forest where there is a continuum of moves. These are marked with arcs, as can be seen in the top part of the figure (above the letter B). I have been able to implement this successfully by looking at an answer to another question here.
In this particular case, however, I would like to have another arc in the same way above the letter D.
I think that I need to define beforehand that Forest does this not only on level 0, but also on level 2. However, I have already tried different ways, unfortunately without satisfactory results.
I would appreciate it if you continue to work with the existing code if possible and do not suggest any other environment that might be suitable instead.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt, multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{forest} 

\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy,backgrounds, through, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{through,calc}

%---------------------------------------------------------

\forestset{%
  auto edge label/.style={%
    before typesetting nodes={%
      if level=0{}{
        if={n()>(n_children("!u")/2)}{
          if={n()==((n_children("!u")+1)/2)}{
            edge label/.wrap value={
              node[midway, right] {$##1$}
            },
          }{
            edge label/.wrap value={
              node[midway, outer sep=1.5mm, right] {$##1$}
            },
          },
        }{
          edge label/.wrap value={
            node[midway, outer sep=1.5mm, left] {$##1$}
          },
        }
      },
    },
  },
  nice empty nodes/.style={% page 65 of the manual - this is from the linguistics library
    for tree={
      calign=fixed edge angles
    },
    delay={
      where content={}{
        shape=coordinate,
        for parent={
          for children={anchor=north}
        }
      }{}
    }
  },
  arc below/.style={
    tikz+={%
      \clip (.center) coordinate (o) -- (!1.north) coordinate (a) |- (!2.north) coordinate (b) -| (!3.north) coordinate (c) -- cycle;
      \node [draw, circle through={(b)}] at (o) {};
      \draw [\forestoption{edge}] () -- ($(o)!1!-35:(b)$) ($(o)!1!35:(b)$) -- ();
    },
    for children={
      if n=2{}{no edge},
    }
  }
}
\tikzset{%
  my circle/.style={draw, circle}
}



\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    l sep=2em,
    s sep=4em,
    auto edge label,
    nice empty nodes,
    math content
    }
  [A, my circle, arc below
    [, coordinate, edge label={0}]
    [B, my circle, edge label={}
        [{C}, my circle, edge label=0,
            [, coordinate , edge label={0}]
            [D, my circle, edge label={}
                [E, my circle, edge label={0}
                    [{0}, edge label={0}]
                    [{0}, edge label={0}]
                ]
                    [{0}, edge label={0}]
            ]
            [ , coordinate, edge label={0}]
       ]
    [{0}, edge label={0}]
    ]
    [, coordinate, edge label={0}]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: Here is the output of my current code.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw the arc below node "C", we simply need to add `arc below` to its specification. But:

The content of `tikz+` in the definition of `arc below` should be enclosed in a `scope` environment, otherwise the clipping from "A"'s arc will apply to the rest of the picture, including the intended arc below "C". (Note that 'the rest of the picture' does not include the nodes (and their edges) which come after node "A", because Forest first draws all the nodes, then all the edges, and only then the additional `tikz` code.)

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt, multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{forest} 

\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy,backgrounds, through, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{through,calc}

%---------------------------------------------------------

\forestset{%
  auto edge label/.style={%
    before typesetting nodes={%
      if level=0{}{
        if={n()>(n_children("!u")/2)}{
          if={n()==((n_children("!u")+1)/2)}{
            edge label/.wrap value={
              node[midway, right] {$##1$}
            },
          }{
            edge label/.wrap value={
              node[midway, outer sep=1.5mm, right] {$##1$}
            },
          },
        }{
          edge label/.wrap value={
            node[midway, outer sep=1.5mm, left] {$##1$}
          },
        }
      },
    },
  },
  nice empty nodes/.style={% page 65 of the manual - this is from the linguistics library
    for tree={
      calign=fixed edge angles
    },
    delay={
      where content={}{
        shape=coordinate,
        for parent={
          for children={anchor=north}
        }
      }{}
    }
  },
  arc below/.style={
    tikz+={%
      \begin{scope}
        \clip (.center) coordinate (o) -- (!1.north) coordinate (a) |- (!2.north) coordinate (b) -| (!3.north) coordinate (c) -- cycle;
        \node [draw, circle through={(b)}] at (o) {};
        \draw [\forestoption{edge}] () -- ($(o)!1!-35:(b)$) ($(o)!1!35:(b)$) -- ();
      \end{scope}
    },
    for children={
      if n=2{}{no edge},
    }
  }
}
\tikzset{%
  my circle/.style={draw, circle}
}



\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    l sep=2em,
    s sep=4em,
    auto edge label,
    nice empty nodes,
    math content
    }
  [A, my circle, arc below
    [, coordinate, edge label={0}]
    [B, my circle, edge label={}
        [{C}, my circle, edge label=0, arc below,
            [, coordinate , edge label={0}]
            [D, my circle, edge label={}
                [E, my circle, edge label={0}
                    [{0}, edge label={0}]
                    [{0}, edge label={0}]
                ]
                    [{0}, edge label={0}]
            ]
            [ , coordinate, edge label={0}]
       ]
    [{0}, edge label={0}]
    ]
    [, coordinate, edge label={0}]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have a further question regarding the implementation of the game tree. In order to make the backwards induction visually recognisable, we use the notation that one or two diagonal lines are drawn through the connection from one level to another (i.e. the parent-child connection). However, I am not aware of any handling that would get this into the Forest environment. @Sašo, do you have any ideas that might help me there as well?

Comment: I admit I'm not sure what precisely you have in mind. Perhaps you could open another question, and provide a picture? (Just draw on the current PDF by hand.)